# Getting error while executing convert. Magic in r studio. How to solve this error

Tags: r, machine-learning

Change a few predictor variables from integer to factors (make dummies)

```
chclass <-c("numeric","factor","factor","numeric","numeric","factor","factor","numeric","factor","numeric","factor","factor","factor","factor")

heart.data <- convert.magic(heart.data,chclass)
```

This is the code which i am trying to execute but i am getting the error as:

```
Error in convert.magic(heart.data,chclass):
   Could not find function "convert.magic"
```

How to solve this error? I have installed magic package.

Answer (score 1):

Function needed to convert classes of predictor values:

```
   convert.magic <- function(obj,types) 
   { for (i in 1:length(obj)) {  FUN
   <- switch(types[i],character = as.character,numeric =
   as.numeric,factor = as.factor) obj[,i] <- FUN(obj[,i]) }  obj }


   convert.names <- function(row){
     row=gsub("sex1", "male", row)
     row=gsub("thal7", "reversable defect thalassemia", row)
     row=gsub("thal6", "fixed defect thalassemia", row)
     row=gsub("cp4", "asymptomatic chest pain", row)
     row=gsub("cp3", "non-anginal chest pain", row)
     row=gsub("cp2", "atypical angina chest pain", row)
     row=gsub("oldpeak", "ST depression from exercise", row)
     row=gsub("thalach", "maximum heart rate achieved", row)
     row=gsub("trestbps", "resting blood pressure", row)
     row=gsub("ca2", "2 major vessels col/b fluoro., ca2", row)
     row=gsub("ca1", "1 major vessel col/b fluoro., ca1", row)
     row=gsub("slope2", "flat peak exercise ST segment", row)
     row=gsub("slope1", "upsloping peak exercise ST segment", row)
     row=gsub("slope3", "downsloping peak exercise ST segment", row)
     row=gsub("chol", "serum cholestoral", row)
     row=gsub("exang", "exercise induced angina", row)
     row=gsub("restecg2", "restec: showing left ventricular hypertrophy
                         by Estes criteria", row)
     row=gsub("restecg1", "restec: having ST-T wave abnormality", row)
     row=gsub("fbs1", "fasting blood sugar > 120 mg/dl", row)
     }
```

Use this function before the chclass.